# apply() and table() return strange list when column only has one value (100%)

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I'm trying to apply the table() function to a matrix in R. I want to know how often a value (0,1) appears per column. 
There's no problem if a column contains both 1 and 0. But if a column contains only 1 or only 0 then apply() returns a strange list instead of a matrix.

How can I make apply to return a matrix like in example 1 for matrix 2?

```
#example 1
good_mat<-matrix(c(c(1,0,1),c(1,0,1),c(0,0,1)), 3,3, byrow=F)
apply(good_mat, 2, FUN=table) # good result, matrix

#example 2
bad_mat<-matrix(c(rep(1,3),c(1,NA,1),c(0,0,1)), 3,3, byrow=F)
apply(bad_mat, 2, FUN=table) # strange list
```

edit: 
matrix can contain NAs

Comment: I'ts not specific to having one value with 100%. It's because the three calculated tables don't have the same values.

Comment: do you have to use `apply` ??

Comment: `apply(bad_mat + 1, 2, tabulate)`

Comment: @Sotos: no. tried aggregate() but couldn't make it work

Comment: Axeman, does not fit my needs. problem consists e.g. with matrix(c(c(1,1,1),c(1,0,1),c(0,0,0)), 3,3, byrow=F)

Comment: As an alternative to your `apply`, see `table(bad_mat, col(bad_mat))`

Comment: @alexis_laz, better than the current answers I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I 'd recommend package `matrixStats`,

```
library(matrixStats)
 rbind(colCounts(good_mat, value = 0, na.rm = TRUE), 
       colCounts(good_mat, value = 1, na.rm = TRUE))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    1    3
#[2,]    3    2    0
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine with ...,na.rm=T)

Answer (score 3):

A base solution:

```
m <- matrix(c(c(1,1,1),c(1,0,1),c(0,0,0)), 3,3, byrow=F)

rbind(nrow(m) - rowSums(m, na.rm = TRUE), rowSums(m, na.rm = TRUE))
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
> [1,]    0    1    3
> [2,]    3    2    0
> ```

Or

```
tmp <- colSums(m, na.rm = TRUE)
rbind(nrow(m) - tmp, tmp)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution with `colSums` to calculate the values and `rbind` to combine the results.

```
rbind((colSums(bad_mat == 0)), (colSums(bad_mat == 1)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    2
[2,]    3    2    1
```

---

or, to generalize over more than binary values, you could wrap this in `lapply` and feed it to `do.call`. Just replace `0:1` with the desired values.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(0:1, function(i) colSums(bad_mat == i)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    2
[2,]    3    2    1
```